How to Dynamically Determine the Repartition Count for Loading Large CSV Files into PostgreSQL Using PySpark?
I need to load 5 million records from a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table as quickly as possible using PySpark. The performance and speed of the operation are critical for me. I often run my code from either my PC or a server, and I suspect the optimal repartition count might differ depending on the environment.
Here are my configurations:
PC Configuration:

RAM: 16 GB
Storage: 256 GB
CPU: 8 cores

Server Configuration:

RAM: 64 GB
Storage: 2 TB
CPU: 32 cores

Tech Stack:

Backend: Django 5.0.7
Python: 3.11.9
Database: PostgreSQL 15
PySpark: 3.5.1

df.repartition(400)
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("csv")
    .save(filepath, header='false')

What I Need:
I want to dynamically determine the number of partitions based on the size of the data, the number of file rows, and the available CPU resources. The goal is to optimize the loading speed. Can someone suggest a dynamic function or strategy to calculate the appropriate repartition count for different environments?

5 million records is not a lot and without any specific load time in mind, you don't have a problem at all. Use COPY to make it faster than INSERT and run your horses.  https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

My guess with a single-node setup like this you'll bottleneck on IO/network bandwidth before anything else.
